# GEO Tag Photo lat/long data conversion

Tags: geotag

I have the following data of a GEOTag photo

---

### GPSMapDatum     WGS-84

### GPSLatitudeRef  N

### 0)              18/1

### 1)              57/1

### 2)              2147483647/89750086

### GPSLongitudeRef E

### 0)              74/1

### 1)              10/1

### 2)              2147483647/54998752

### GPSAltitudeRef

### GPSAltitude         2147483647/3510369

### GPSImgDirectionRef  T

### GPSImgDirection     2147483647/81244832

My question is how can i convert this data to proper lat/long co-ordinates
(eg: 18.1234, -74.1234).

Comment: Guess: 0 is degree, 1 is minutes, and perform the division in 2 to get the seconds portion or possibly the decimal portion of the minutes. Should the altitude be around 600m?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EXIF GeoTags for Lat and Long are expressed as integers numerator / denominator for each of degrees, minutes, and seconds. So the decimal latitude in the case is:

GPSLatitudeRef N

0) 18/1

1) 57/1

2) 2147483647/89750086

degrees = 18/1 = 18

minutes = 57/1 = 57

seconds = 2147483647/89750086 = 23.92

DMS = 18d 57m 23.92s

18 + 57/60 + 23.92/3600 =

18 + 0.95 * 0.006644 = 18.956644 degrees North Latitude